# Can an electric stovetop burner be damaged from prolonged use without cookware on it?

Tags: heat

My partner, who does building maintenance, thinks that it may be possible to damage an electric stove top burner by extended use without a pot or pan because the heating element doesn’t have something to dissipate the heat into.

To me it seems like the heat would just be dissipated into the air, and the element wouldn’t get and hotter than its max setting.

I found some information about thermal regulators, but it’s not clear to me exactly how they work or if they work the same without cookware on the burner. We also have a very old stove and aren’t sure if the technology would be the same.

I have searched quite a bit but mostly found information about people leaving things on the burner unattended and then catching fire, or about faulty wiring, etc. I’m just wondering if a burner with nothing on it could overheat and burn out the element. Will the burner get hotter with nothing on it?

(The backstory is that I occasionally take the cookware off the burner between cooking ingredients so that I’m not damaging the cookware while there’s nothing in it, while I take a minute or two to prep the next ingredients for the pot.)

Edit: this is not a glass cook top, it's regular electric burners. I have viewed inside the oven that the model is J CS66 0W2AD. The serial number indicates it is from March of 1980. The maker is  General Electric.

Comment: Yes, the burner would certainly get hotter without a heat sink. Whether or not that would cause damage, I don’t know. Either way, I can’t think of a good reason to leave a stove burning with nothing on it.

Comment: A glass stove top user and care guide does not address this issue and is not an issue regarding warranty.  If it were a problem the manufacturer would address it in the manual.  Any potential issues would have been resolved by the designers.   No manufacturer wants more field service issues.  Regarding the backstory, leaving empty cookware  on the burner can (has by my experience) damage the cookware.

Comment: Leah What make and model?

Comment: It's General Electric manufactured in March 1980. Model: J CS66 0W2AD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it encourages people to be wasteful of energy. Don't do it. Have you heard the news recently?

Answer (score 3):

An older stove element likely uses no active thermal regulator. It will run hotter, brighter when you remove cookware. It should be safe to run this way (from an electrical point-of-view).
However, watch for a hot spot, where one small section of the element is brighter...an indication that the element is damaged, at risk of imminent failure.

Comment: Given the "thermal regulation" of a stove top is a bi-metallic thermostat, how does the cookware removal  make the element brighter?  Or hotter?

Comment: @Misunderstood I'm old (and my stove is older than me.) *My* old stove has no thermal regulator on its top elements. Oven does have a thermostat. "Very old stove" is a too-loose spec - don't know when active element control became common.

Answer (score 2):

Relax, there is no problem with not having a pot on the burner.
Take a look at what is under the ceramic glass top.

- The heating elements.
- A probe to conduct heat.
- A control box with thermostatic contacts

As the air around the heating element gets hot the heat is conducted from the probe to the control box.  There is one set of contacts for the "burner hot" indicator and one limiting the temperature of the heating elements.

[image]

[image]

---

### Conclusion

From the above you can clearly see it does not matter if there is a pot on the stove top or not.

There are no reflections from the pot involved and no mysterious sensors.  Nothing to do with Color Temperature, not related to light bulb filament lifespan, or infrared waves.  The heating element has no variable brightness, only off or on.

Comment: the probe is actually two dissimilar materials and when it heats up the end of the inner part moves relative to the outer part.

Comment: @Jasen thanks.  Maybe you could help me explain that to Tony Stewart older than dirt.  If you look at the comments to his answer you will see I am struggling with explaining to him the concept of bi-metallic vs. his (imaginary or real?) cookware reflection to a mysterious sensor.

Comment: dude's older than dirt, his brain has turned to rock.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so (something shiny like a stainless steel pot bottom is worse because it reflects the IR back into the heater on smooth top ranges), but the element and the (usually mechanical) device that drives it  both have a finite life, so you're wearing them unnecessarily.

Also it sucks electrical energy, which is wasteful and costs money if you don't need it.

Also, it is possible to forget it and leave it on for a long time, which is wasteful (and even if the burner is not vacant it could easily damage an aluminum or non-stick coated pot).

I would say you should turn it off if you're not using for more than about 30 seconds.

---

Not related to the burner per se, but if you allow a smooth top cooktop to get very hot and place a pot with a wet bottom onto it (or let bit of liquid overflow onto it) you could induce crack propagation from a minor scratch and b*gger the whole top. At that point it's typically more sensible to replace the entire range or cooktop. Crazy expensive.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of thermostatic tops the temperature sensor needs to contact cookware for them to regulate their heat,  for those with just a power setting if there's no cookware cooling them down they will get hotter than usual, I've seen them get hot enough to melt aluminium. also seen them glowing orange,

Comment: How does the temperature sensor contact the cookware?

Answer (score 0):

> My partner, who does building maintenance, thinks that it may be possible to damage an electric stove top burner by extended use without a pot or pan because the heating element doesn’t have something to dissipate the heat into.

Lots of [people disagree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spots_(cannabis)), particularly in New Zealand.

"May be possible", OK, it "may be possible". I've used the stovetop as a heater, never burned them out. People sometimes leave them on, it happens. The heat dissipates into the air.

[image: Hot Knife]

Does he think if he goes outside it "may be possible" to get hit by lightning, thus he never goes out? What about driving a car or walking on a sidewalk ... just think what could happen!

Comment: hot knifing is legal there yet?  I think this post will have a half-life of 10 minutes. But thanks for your non EE contribution to science

Comment: I had to look that term up - and then I found that image.

Comment: @Jasen hot knifing refers to heating the knives red hot then picking up a small piece of hashish with one red hot knife then squeezing the piece of hash between the two red hot knives.  The photo comes from Wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spots_(cannabis)

Comment: yeah... that's where I found that image,  I'd heard of spotting.

Answer (score -2):

> Overall I would say listen to your husband even if he's wrong.
>
> But in theory your husband is correct.  In practise, you need a model number and data to support it.

(correction) Without a pot, there is less reflection to the sensor so the element will be slightly hotter and may appear a brighter red according to it's color vs temperature.

2nd correction. If your stove is really old like mid60's it wont have any temperature sensing and just has resistance elements switched by Low, MedLow, Med, Med-Hi, Hi

1000'C = Bright Cherry Red
500'C = dim Red

If removing your pot keeps the element to 500'C (dim Red) at areas of contact then rises to Bright Cherry Red that is equivalent to 1000'C and means the lifetime will significantly be reduced in hours of MTBF due to an effect called Arhenius Law which states failure rates double every 10'C rise when there are no defects.

But since we don't know how many centuries it will last at room temp its hard to predict. But like a light bulb at 2500'C  if enclosed in a small globe , it may raise the bulb filament temp 40'C and only last 1/16 of 2000 hours ( estimate ).
[image]

But in the end it may not make any difference as the pot does not make contact with the entire elemment all the time and if some parts are still Cherry Red , they become the weak link in the chain and will break there.

> So it wont matter if the pot is on or not.  It has a limited lifespan.

Comment: Reflections?  Sensor? Color temperature? Light bulb filament?  I do not down vote answers, but if I did...  The correct answer is the cookware has zero effect upon the burner.

Comment: Not so, a the load creates greater thermal gradient and coefficient of expansion stresses. No load creates a hotter red  surface but a lower gradient. across the element.   Arrhenius Law prevails on higher temps and the rugged design can withstand the gradients. So in Theory degradation rate of material doubles every 10'C rise approx. due to temperature. But that in normal use can be 60 yrs or 10 yrs (for eg) depending more now on defects than fake MTBF.

Comment: Really?  You are going to defend your answer?  Good luck with that.  Still think there are reflections and mysterious color temperature sensors?  Still think a heating element resembles a light bulb filament?  I'm not sure what is more frightening, your answer or this response to my comment.

Comment: color temperature is physics and Arhennius Law is chemistry, both are related.  YOu are confused. There is an adjustable thermal sensor not a color sensor on modern stove tops.

Comment: Nothing reflects from the pot to a sensor as you have implied. Whether physics blackbodies (color temp) or Arhennius [sic],  neither (not both) applies to a stove top.   There is no sensor, just simple a bi-metallic contact reed.  See the photos in my answer.

Comment: You must have a really old stove in mind ... and dont understand how thermal resistance in a string affect temperatures rise from loading. Just like Ohm's Law for voltages. https://www.repairclinic.com/Shop-For-Parts/a13i2587/Range-Stove-Oven-Temperature-Sensor-Parts  If I assumed wrong OP please correct me. But variable heat stovetops have analog sensors. Even variable bimetallic are analog.  But load does affect proximity temp. just as in Ohm's Law it affects voltage at source resistance from load regulation error.

Comment: I looked at your link to "sensors". I still do not see how the reflection from the cookware to the "sensor" comes into play.   Is 10 years old considered "really old".  I just looked at the Whirlpool stove I bought a year ago and is looks very similar to the 10 year old Jannair I had 10 years ago (the one pictured in my answer). What is this "load" you refer to?  Yes, I do not understand how thermal resistance in a string applies.  I also do not see how ohms law apples to the expansion and contraction of a bi-metallic "sensor".  Oh wait. I was thinking ceramic glass top stove. That's not old.

Comment: I used to have a Kingsize waterbed in 1974 when I got married. The thermistor was directly under the vinyl mattress. My controller I made had a hysteresis of about 0.5deg and ever time I dove into bed the sensor rose from lower thermal resistance and the relay heater clicked off. then on a fewer minutes later.

Comment: But all kidding aside now. Yes in an PID loop and yours is only P feedback, the temp set error is affected by loading just as any PSU output impedance determines step load regulation error.  The sensor is non contact to the pot so there is thermal resistance to it and the load does affect the filament temp.  Also applies to ceramic stove tops

Comment: Wow a mid 70's waterbed with a thermistor.  That must have been super high tech.  My 70's waterbed had a thin (about 1/16" dia) copper tubing going from the thermostat to larger copper tube about 6" long and 3/16" in diameter.  In the mid 80s I paid over $100 for a thermostat with a thermistor to get the small hysteresis.  I cannot imagine how expensive a thermistor based thermostat would have been in the 70's, probably more than I paid for my waterbed and heater.  I was still in school, paying rent, very poor, and very skinny (couldn't afford food) in the 70's.  But had a waterbed! Yea!

Comment: I'm sorry, you are over my head.  I do not know PID or P feedback.  I am completely lost when you mention a the output impedance of a PSU and how it relates to the reflection off the cookware to the stove top sensor.   So a stove top heating element is also called a filament?  So is that why you earlier referred to a thermal string (latin filum  = thread)?  I cannot keep up with you.  You own stuff before it is invented.  How can I possibly keep up with that?

Comment: Husband?  Really?  She said partner.  You may be older than dirt but that's no excuse.

Comment: I told my religious friends who don’t know us well enough that my (2nd) wife and I were married 1 yrs ago by a Minister . Under the department of the Minister of Finance (lol). But on a serious note P proportional control systems which all have load regulation error. Just all Power supplies due to coupling loss and feedback gain and bimetalic springs have low gain. And wrong again , my water temp controller was $5 since the few hrs to put together was free

Comment: Yes old stove tops used multiple nichrome filament wires to select the power levels open loop

Comment: I learned from the shoulders of giants like all the trade journals on Electronic Design before I graduated then HP, Tektronix, Aerospace R&D was my 1st of 6 technologies in my career, and like Tweed knew enough to produce functional successes right out of school. What he did for Burroughs CPU’s , I did for Doppler Nav systems alone on my 1st gig.